# Using Langchain Opensearch with NextJS

Tags: next.js, opensearch, langchain, langchain-js

I want to use [Langchain's Opensearch vector store integration](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/vectorstores/integrations/opensearch), but it's marked as a node.js-only integration.

Is it possible for this to work with NextJS? I tried but ended up getting several errors inside the node_module opensearch folder, related to modules not being found.

Comment: yes its possible, you need to install all dependencies and create appropriate architecture to do so.